# Sqoop jobs ask for password even when record password is set to true in sqoop-site.xml

Tags: sqoop

I have created some sqoop jobs and have set `record password to true`. I am running these jobs through oozie. I have 10-12 jobs which I am running from oozie and after executing around 6-7 jobs, it throws

Could not connect to user@host (using password NO).

How come it stops using the recorded password after executing a couple of times? When I recreate job again, ti works fine a couple of time 'and then again the same problem with the same error.

I really need to know what is causing this issue?There has to be a valid reason for this,ain't it? Recreating the job is certainly not the fix neither is restarting the SQL server I am connecting to.

My sqoop jobs look like this:

```
sqoop job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://FQDN:16000/sqoop --create sample_job -- import --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect jdbc:mysql://IP/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull --username USERNAME --password 'PASSWORD' --table tableName --merge-key id --split-by id --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-database erpdb
```

My typical sqoop job execution command look like this in workflow:

```
job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://FQDN:16000/sqoop  --exec sample_job -- --warehouse-dir DIRNAME
```

Infact, I checked the property:

```
sqoop job --meta-connect  jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://FQDN:16000/sqoop  --exec job_name
```

and it returns `false`.

Comment: Did you pass that `sqoop-site.xml` config to the Sqoop action with a `<job-xml>` command? If yes, why bother adding these silly command-line options e.g. `--meta-connect` is just a shortcut for `sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect` to True and `sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url ` to the URL, cf. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_6

Comment: Did you try to force the property on the command-line with `-D sqoop.metastore.client.record.password=true` since the conf file is not "magically" exposed to Sqoop?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: I added hive-site.xml to job-xml component in the workflow using hue editor but my question is that how come it is picking configuration for some sqoop jobs in that case? Why does it start asking for password only after executing a couple of jobs?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to debug that thing yourself -- dig out the YARN logs for a job that requires the password and for another job that doesn't, and try to find a difference. Also, connect to the HSQLDB instance (using any kind of JDBC utility) before/after each Oozie job and check that the record storing the pwd has not been deleted for some reason.

Comment: Alright! It really took long to come up with this but I have shared an elaborate solution to the problem here: http://www.yourtechchick.com/sqoop/sqoop-job-fails-to-record-password-after-running-for-the-first-time-problem-fix/

Answer (score 0):

sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect to True .
change the same to sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect to true ... It will work